# Is $\{{(0,0)}\cup{(\frac1n,\sin\frac1n)\,|\,n=1,2,3,\dots}\}$ a compact set?

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this problem on an old test paper that didn't come with an answer. I tried to search the internet and didn't find an answer.
(I'm quite a newbie here, tell me if I shouldn't post such questions here)

I think it was a compact but I can't think up a proper proof.

To prove it, I tried to prove it's bounded and closed.
Obviously it's bounded, I failed to prove that it's a closed set.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: For large $n$, notice that $1/n$ is small and therefore $\sin(1/n) \approx 1/n$.

Comment: For closing you need all limit points to be in set ...

Comment: Prove a more general result: If $x_n \to x$ in metric space then $\{x,x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out.

Points in this set are discrete. For any nonzero point P, there exists an r, $\forall q\in S,q\not\in O(P,r)$. Then q is not a limit point.

So any nonzero point is not a limit point.
Obviously, zero point is the only limit point.
So the set is closed and bounded, thus compact.

Comment: Well done. I tried looking for a duplicate but couldn't find one.